# What's the difference in usage between "install" and "instill"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Is there actually any difference between the words?  I feel like I am perfectly capable of *installing* a healthy fear in someone.

Comment: Nope, *install* a fear is incorrect.

Comment: Yes. Unless “fear” is the name of some sort of organ or appliance, you really can’t install it. :)

Comment: Do you assume that "bat" and "bot" are interchangeable because they differ by only one letter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elobarating on @Eldros answer.

You install a quantifiable object and it can be counted. (Installed one software, installed the President, installed two chairs etc.)

You instill a quality (fear, confidence) which cannot be counted

Answer (score 3):

From Collins Cobuild English Dictionary:

> install: If you install a piece of
>   equipment, you fit it or put it
>   somewhere so that it is ready to be
>   used. *They had installed a new phone
>   line in the apartment.*
>
> instil/instill(AM): If you instil an
>   idea or feeling in someone, especially
>   over a period of time, you make them
>   think it or feel it. *They hope that
>   their work will instil a sense of
>   responsibility in children.*

So, definitely a difference.

Answer (score 1):

*To install* can only be used on physical object (The excpetion would be piece of software, where it could be compared to a piece of equipment for the computer system). Thus *fear*, an emotion, can't be installed.

In can be *instilled*, as could idea and feelings. And when one *instill fear*, it is quite frightening, as it imply the feeling slowling creeping and taking hold on ones mind...

Comment: Actually, "install" is also used of formally initiating somebody in an office or position: "installation of the new Chancellor [of the University]". But that is quite a formal and uncommon use.

Comment: @Colin : Didn't knew about this use, but it makes sense, when we would compare that to "adding/replacing an extension to the actual hierarchy", if you see what I mean.